# Display array elements in angular template

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to display values of an array from a *ngFor

```
const blockData = [
    {text: sampleText1, array: [val1]},
    {text: sampleText2, array: [val2, dat2]},
    {text: sampleText3, array: [val3, dat3]}
]

<div *ngFor="let data of blockData">{{data.text}} 
<span>{{data.array}}</span></div>
```

How to display my both `data.array` values in my span

Comment: You mean like this? `<span>{{data.array.join(',')}}</span></div>` - or did you want to loop through the array values with another `*ngFor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ng-container and loop inside of your initial loop. Make sure that you clean up your blockData array and wrap the values inside quotes.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of blockData">{{data.text}} 
    <span>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data.array"> - {{item}} - </ng-container>
    </span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const blockData = [
    {text: sampleText1, array: [val1]},
    {text: sampleText2, array: [val2, dat2]},
    {text: sampleText3, array: [val3, dat3]}
]
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of blockData">{{data.text}} 
<span *ngFor="let val of data.array">{{val}}</span>
</div>
```

Can't you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json` pipe for that

```
const blockData = [
    {text: sampleText1, array: [val1]},
    {text: sampleText2, array: [val2, dat2]},
    {text: sampleText3, array: [val3, dat3]}
]

<div *ngFor="let data of blockData">{{data.text}} 
<span>{{data.array | json}}</span></div>
```